# Has there ever been an instance of a business attempting or succeed a coup?

Tags: business-history, coup

Has there ever been an instance of a business attempting or succeed a coup? If not then are there any instances of business supporting ''rebel'' forces?

Comment: The British [East India company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_Company)  comes to mind (repeatedly) as does Hawaii and United Fruit. Entering your question into google results in a citation from [Foreign Policy](http://foreignpolicy.com/2013/08/20/mapped-the-7-governments-the-u-s-has-overthrown/)

Comment: Researching [This question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/what-was-reason-for-the-dutch-attack-on-venezuela-in-1908/35089#35089) revealed rebel forces funded by a corporation after the local government had nationalized resources. I imagine that is not an uncommon occurrence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has happened several times between U.S. companies and Latin American countries.

The [United Fruit Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Guatemalan_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat) was a major player in a 1954 coup in Guatemala.

[A 1973 coup in Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_intervention_in_Chile) was allegedly backed by International Telephone and Telegraph.

Comment: The US conducted an entire series of wars on behalf of corporations known as the [Banana Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Wars) from which we get the term "Banana Republic".